# React-Bootstrap: Set Panel width to Panel.Collapse width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a React-Bootstrap Panel with a short title but possibly wide collapsible content, like so:

```
<Panel>
  <Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Title toggle>
      Hello
    </Panel.Title>
  </Panel.Heading>
  <Panel.Collapse>
    <Panel.Body>
      Really wide body. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </Panel.Body>
  </Panel.Collapse>
</Panel>
```

This results in a really thin Panel.Heading when collapsed, but a really wide Panel.Heading when expanded, like so:

[image]
[image]

My question is, how can I make the width of my Panel.Heading match the width of Panel.Body, even when collapsed?

Comment: the code looks good. Can you please show your complete component?

Comment: What do you mean? The code compiles, yes, but the Panel heading's width does not match the body's width when the body is collapsed. See how thin it is in the first picture?

Comment: That's not your code. The Title is "Short title". But your screen shows "Hello". 
The code provided by react-bootstrap works well.

Comment: The title in my code being the same as in the images I published is irrelevant to my question, but I have edited it now for your sake.

Comment: like I said. The code is ok. You must check the applied css classes. (for example with chrome dev-tools)